# Xsl nested loop

Tags: xslt

I'm having a problem with a nested loop.  The variable is out of scope when I try to select it back out. I understand why (I think), but I don't know what my options are to fix it.

```
          <xsl:for-each select="/objects/InstalledSQLServices">
              <xsl:variable name="InstalledService" select="./Property[@Name ='Name']"></xsl:variable>
              <tr>
                <td align="left">
                  <xsl:value-of select="./Property[@Name ='DisplayName']"/>
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                  <xsl:value-of select="./Property[@Name ='Status']"/>
                </td>
                <xsl:for-each select="/objects/SqlVersion">
                  <xsl:variable name="SqlInstance" select="concat('MSSQL$',./Property[@Name ='Instance'])"></xsl:variable>
                  <xsl:variable name="SqlDescription">
                    <xsl:choose>
                      <xsl:when test="$InstalledService=$SqlInstance">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(./Property[@Name ='Version'],' ', ./Property[@Name ='Edition'])"/>
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:otherwise>                            
                        <xsl:value-of select="None"/>
                      </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>       
                  </xsl:variable>                 
                </xsl:for-each>
                <td align="left" style="color: rgb(255,0,0); font-weight: bold">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$SqlDescription"/>      
                </td>   
              </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I want to grab the value from a different node in the xml document if there is a match for the current node.  So, if /objects/InstalledSQLServices/Name = /objects/SqlVersion/Instance, populate a column with attributes from /objects/SqlVersion/Instance (edition, version, etc...)

Comment: Answered my own question, it was just a matter of getting the looping corrected

Comment: @sqlpadawan Either close it, or post the answer and accept it so that others can benefit from it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I ended up using:

```
          <xsl:for-each select="/objects/InstalledSQLServices">
            <xsl:variable name="InstalledService" select="./Property[@Name ='Name']"></xsl:variable>
            <tr>
              <td align="left">
                <xsl:value-of select="./Property[@Name ='DisplayName']"/>
              </td>
              <td align="left">
                <xsl:value-of select="./Property[@Name ='Status']"/>
              </td>
              <td align="left">
                <xsl:for-each select="/objects/GetSqlVersion">
                  <xsl:variable name="SqlInstance" select="concat('MSSQL$',./Property[@Name ='Instance'])"></xsl:variable>
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$InstalledService=$SqlInstance">
                      <xsl:value-of select="concat(./Property[@Name ='Version'],' ',./Property[@Name ='Edition'],' ',./Property[@Name ='fullVer'],' ',./Property[@Name ='Level'])"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:value-of select="'&#160;'"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
```